# d3 timelines chart has a large amount of labels so they overlap. How do I selectively show labels based on chart size?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, charts

Here's the component I am using: https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/ded69192b8269a78d2d97e24211e64e0

my chart is implemented as shown on the link, however, the amount of data I have is much greater. Is there a way to show a select amount of labels until a user zooms in so there isn't overlap? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "until a user zooms", what kind of zoom do you mean? I ask because the horizontal zoom would hardly bring more space to the labels, since the problem is in vertical space. A zoom mechanic that could help is a continuous vertical zoom where the user increases the range of the vertical scales, which would gradually increase vertical space for labels on zoom. Is that the interaction you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thanks for the response. In the example posted, you can click and drag to create a box, the chart will then zoom in so that box fills the chart. This is the zoom I'm talking about. So what I'm looking to do is basically either not show any labels, or just show a few labels, until a user zooms in enough for all labels that are in the window to be visible without overlapping.